# vqmod logs opencart error

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod

I had installed an extension which was working great, but after doing some modification it stopped working. and i was going through the vqmod/logs and found this error, can anyone please solve this issue?

REQUEST URI : /index.php?route=product/category&path=81

MOD DETAILS:

modFile   : /home/public_html/vqmod/xml/add_option_category.xml

id        :

version   : 1.0

vqmver    :

author    : OST

File Name    : catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/category.tpl(5)

VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (ABORTING MOD)

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes you have made are conflicting with this existing mod, hence the error.

The message is saying that this line:

```
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
```

Is not found in this file: catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/category.tpl because it has been hardcoded out or another vqmod is modifying that code before your old one is.

get in touch with the mod author and they can adjust the script for you, it's a very simple change.